# Why --i and i-1 producing diffrent output in recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have two method, the difference is one is having --i1 and other is having i-1, however they are producing different output.

```
 String s1 = "axbdcg";
        String s2 ="aazzzzzzzzzzzzcbc";
        System.out.println(method(s1,s2,s1.length()-1,s2.length()-1));


 int method(String s1, String s2, int i1, int i2){
    if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) return 0;
    if(i1 < 0|| i2 < 0) return 0;
    if(s1.charAt(i1) ==  s2.charAt(i2)) return 1+  method(s1,s2,--i1,--i2);
int left = method(s1,s2,--i1,i2);

int right =  method(s1,s2,i1,--i2);
         return Math.max(left ,right);
    }
```

this method is giving 2 as output and

```
     int method(String s1, String s2, int i1, int i2){
    if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) return 0;
    if(i1 < 0|| i2 < 0) return 0;
    if(s1.charAt(i1) ==  s2.charAt(i2)) return 1+  method(s1,s2,--i1,--i2);
int left = method(s1,s2,i1-1,i2);

int right =  method(s1,s2,i1,--i2);
         return Math.max(left ,right);
    }
```

is giving 3 as output.

Comment: Because `--i` changes the value of `i` and `i-1` does not. And since you use `i` again on the next  line, that makes a difference.

Comment: The two programs are not equal. In the first, the first call (`int left = method(s1,s2,--i1,i2);`) decrements the value of `i1` as side-effect of `--i1`. For the subsequent call (`int right =  method(s1,s2,i1,--i2);`), the value of `i1` is thus "one lower". For the second, the first call (`int left = method(s1,s2,i1-1,i2);`) does not change the value of `i1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo(--i)` means following:

1. decrement `i` with `-1`
2. assign a new value to `i`
3. put modified value `i` to the method `foo()`

***P.S.** `i` is modified*

---

`foo(i - 1)` means following:

1. decrement `i` with `-1`
2. put modified value `i` to the method `foo()`

***P.S.** `i` is not modified*

---

So the difference is when you call `method(s1,s2,i1,--i2)` in the first snippet, `i` is being changed, but in the second one - is not.